# How to get correct datetime in django for timezone

Tags: python, django, postgresql, date, datetime

I have this in my settings file

`USE_TZ = True`

Now my timezone is `Europe/Paris`

Now I am saving the datetime in django like this

`obj.start_date = datetime.strptime('Apr 27 2015  9:00AM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')`

I know in databse django saves utc format. In DB its like

`2015-04-26 23:00:00+00`

My Problem is i do calculation based on date

I entered date `27 April` but in databse it gets stored as `26 April`

when i do `obj.start_date.date()` then i get 26 April , instead i want 27 April

also time also comes as different.

My All calculation goes wrong.

What command i need to use to get correct date and time

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Django Timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/), it uses aware datetime objects instead of naive (when using the datetime library). The docs have many examples of how to utilize the timezones for converting into the timezone you want in both views and templates.

Also look at the [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) library, which Django recommends you install as well.

Comment: Thanks for that i have read that  many times but could not understand fully. Can you please show me how will my code look if i have to make that work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when creating datetime object you're not supplying any information about it's timezone. Therefore it is created as a naive datetime, which results in wrong value stored.

Try this:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

tz_france = timezone('Europe/Paris')
loc_dt = tz_france.localize(datetime.strptime('Apr 27 2015  9:00AM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'))
```

It should give you localized datetime object, which can be correctly transformed to UTC by Django and saved in database. The example comes from http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: use `is_dst=None` to raise an exception for ambiguous or non-existent times as [django docs demonstrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage)